# UIScrollview, how to scroll a page under another window

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a UISCrollview loading webviews, as the user starts scrolling to go to the next page, I need to have the the coming webpage to scroll into the screen from underneath another UIView that is stationary, I tried changing the alpha but its not really what I am looking for. how can I accomplish that?
For example, the scroll direction is top to bottom, now I have a uiview at the top of the screen which has some static data showing ( title, location, and other text labels ), and as the user scrolls down I want the content to scroll underneath the label ui view. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: What problems are you having? What have you tried? As long as your view hierarchy is correct, you should have no problem displaying a simple label over a scroll view. I'm having trouble envisioning your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly I'd say you can't do this with a UIScrollView. Instead, you could have separate views for each UIWebView and handle the panning of one view under another with a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Also, did you know there can be conflicts when using UIWebView's inside UIScrollView's?

Comment: Hi rich, What kind of conflicts have you seen for webviews in UIScrollViews?

Comment: The documentation for UIWebView states: 

Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled

Comment: Rich, thanks for this, its a crappy project anyway but now I can show the client this documentation.